# How to display WKWebView content inside a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

following code is working but the problem is that this view is in Navigation so the html content goes behind navigation. I want to add another container view inside safe Area and then display html content there. I tried adding a container view and assigning webView to that container view but it didn't work as screen shows black. Can anyone let me know if we can do it and how?

import UIKit
    import WebKit

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!
var content: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let htmlString = "<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'/></head><body>" + content
        + "</body></head></html>"

    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL:nil)
}

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    webView.uiDelegate = self

    view = webView
}
```

}

Comment: I believe that you need to set the frame to .zero or whatever you're using on the instantiation of the webView var. `webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)` You might also want set a WKWebconfiguration variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame of `webView`

```
webView.frame = CGRect(/* set x, y, wifth and height here*/)
```

or use some autolayout constraints

```
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(webView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    webView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
    webView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    webView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
])
```